# how do I pull files in .gitignore?

Tags: git

just cloned a repository but did not pull files that are in .gitignore file.

for example,

> config.properties

file was not pulled from remote server but I do want to pull the file locally

Comment: Are you sure the file actually exists remotely?

Comment: The file has not been tracked and it does not exist in the remote repository, at least not on the branch you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

If `config.properties` is not present in the remote repository, it won't be pulled.

And since it is part of a `.gitignore`, it won't be added locally (not unless you do a `git add -f config.properties`)

If you force add a file, commit and push, then the next clone will get that file, even if it is listed in a `.gitignore`.